# Excel formula rewrite

Tags: excel-formula

```
=IF( AND( NOT(ISBLANK(I4)) , NOT(ISBLANK(G4)) ),
    IF( AND( OR(W4="Wed",W4="Thu",W4="Fri") , I4<=F4+5 , "Yes","No" ) )
```

I am struggling with the above formula. the first IF part is fine since I am just checking the validity of a couple of date fields I4 and G4, one of which (I4) I use in the second IF statement.

Let me explain the second "IF" part. I am auditing completion date (I4) of Section 2 of Form I-9s by my company. Companies have 3 business days to complete this section. I do however realize that the 3rd day may overlap into the weekend, thus I have to be cognizant to count 5 days from hire date (F4) when a hire is done on Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.

If the hire is done on a Saturday, I have to count 4 days from hire date (F4).

Hires done on Sunday, Monday and Tuesday are fine for a count of 3 business days, for example a hire on Monday has all business days through the 3rd day ending on Thursday.

Can you please help me write the second "IF" statement to accommodate this logic? Your help is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i think your parenthesis is wrong some where for the second IF statement

Answer (score 0):

Initially, looking at your formula it seems that you did not "close" the AND function with a right parenthesis : IF( AND( OR(W4="Wed",W4="Thu",W4="Fri") , I4<=F4+5), "Yes","No" ) )  ... (immediately after the "I4<=F4+5").

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As others have pointed out the issue of your formula, here you have another way next time to check the quality of your formula.

On the pic above, when your mouse is pointing to the 2nd `IF` statement, then you click the `fx` sign that I circled in the pic.  This way, it will show you what you are missing.  I have already added the missing parenthesis in the formula.

However, this is not done yet.  Now if I move my cursor to the 1st `IF`, you will see the `FALSE` statement is missing a value there as the pic shown below.  Of course it is okay to leave it blank but it is not a good design and not recommended to leave the condition out.  This is either the logic is not thoroughly considered or the formula itself is buggy.  Just my suggestion but it is up to you to determine how you want this to be and hopefully this will help you to debug your issue next time.

[image]

Comment: Your suggestions and corrections were so helpful. Have a great week everybody. Mensah.

Comment: Please upvote or tick as the answer (under downvote button) if this helps you to solve the issue.